# "The application does not have a valid signature" Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I'm getting the weirdest error today.

> "The application does not have a valid signature"

I get this error when I try to run the application from Xcode 4.3 on my device.  Also when I archive it shows it as a generic archive instead of a real app.

Of course I deleted all of the invalid profiles, cleaned my derived data, cleaned my target, and restarted.  No luck.

**EDIT:** Turns out that I had a folder reference in my app.  I removed all of the references to the folders and made them groups and it worked!

Comment: independentlyof that - I would definitely recommend to upgrade to xCode 4.4. I had so many problems with 4.3, most of them where resoolved in 4.4

Comment: I agree. Too many bugs in 4.3. I'm downloading 4.4.1 now. Hopefully all problems will be solved.

Comment: @Inturbidus: Can  you explain how you found and removed folder reference?

Comment: Well they are blue inside of the Xcode file list instead of yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had a folder reference in my app. I removed all of the references to the folders and made them groups and it worked!

Comment: Ok, but are we not allowed to have folder references? ;(

Answer (score 28):

Just throwing this out there, might help someone in the future (and also would be good for my future reference).

I have a bigger project with 2 projects within (an API and the main project that is running on the device itself and which uses the API).

I have solved this problem by cleaning both projects and then rebuilding them.

Comment: Product -> Alt -> Clean Build Folder

Answer (score 5):

Ohhh...Cleaning the Project solved my problem..cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

This saved me: http://www.two-tails.com/2010/01/12/the-application-does-not-have-a-valid-signature/

Basically you cannot have a folder reference called "resources"!  I changed to "rsrc" and magic.

Comment: Thank you, this was my issue I have changed the folder to assets

Comment: Link leads to a 404 page not found ;(

Comment: Like I summarized and what was my issue, I had a folder named "resources" which was causing the error.  I renamed to "rsrc" and the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a more detailed error message in the device log, which is extremely valuable for debugging this issue.

In **XCode 7.3**: **Window -> Devices -> Select your device -> At the bottom** there is an error log with detailed information.

For example in my case it outputs something like this:

```
Failed to install application at file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging ... : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620391,
ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of
/private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iKT2NH/extracted/XYZ.app
/Frameworks/Raygun4iOS.framework : 0xe8008019 (The application does not have a valid signature.)}
```

So in my case it is somehow caused by the Raygun framework that I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that when you go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme the Build Configuration is set to Running.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a few hours, but it seems that if you have a framework listed under "Embedded Binaries" as well as being imported through a swift bridging header, this error comes up. I am running XCode 8 with iOS 10. I would try removing your framework from the embedded binaries tab under general settings of your XCode projects. Hope this helps out some person in the future!