# The Application does not have valid signature?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

[image]I know this question is posted so many times but none of answer is helpful to me so once again i asked this question.i am in trouble please help me

I've check if signature valid and i go "**explicit requirement satisfied**"

I am searching for solution from last two days and i've look this links

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079817/the-application-does-not-have-a-valid-signature-xcode-4-3)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102909/ios-xcode6-application-signature-not-valid)

[link3](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/33811-your-application-does-not-have-a-valid-signature/)

[trouble shooting failed signature varification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777-CH1-TNTAG38)

After tired from searching, i create new project and paste all codes to project.
and it's run successfully on device Yesterday. but as soon as i open project today and run , i got same nightmare error! i don't exactly understand what exactly problem is? please help me!